# Is it necessary that $ \lim_{X \to 0} \int_0^x f(\theta)d\theta = 0 ??$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Is it necessary that $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \int_0^x f(\theta)d\theta = 0 ??$$

Like whenever I solve the question with integration and limits , L'Hopitals Rule is pretty much the only option, but which is valid for only $\frac{0}{0}$ type , so is it necessary for it to be zero. Like I understand the explanation of it being area under graph, but what if the function has an infinite value at $x = 0$.

Are there any counter examples of this being false ??
If it is generally true ?? Why ??

In highschool, so don't know what reimann Integral means as some of the answers say...Sorry!

Comment: Is $f$ of any special form?

Comment: No, just a normal function...

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $|f|\leqslant M$. Which means that
$$\left|\int_0^x f\right| \leqslant \int_0^x |f|\leqslant \int_0^x M=Mx$$
And now use the non-negativity of the absolute value and the squeeze theorem.

Comment: In highschool, so don't know what reimann Integral means , but if there is no counterexample at  highschool level, then it will probably not be asked . Thank you so much for your time and effort :)

Comment: Is there any good undergrad level book where I can read about all this ??

Comment: @DivMit Usually, you will face the Riemann integral in high school only, without the "Riemann" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;f\;$ is Riemann integrable, then $\;\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt\;$ is a continuous function of $\;x\;$ , and thus the result follows at once. If the function isn't integrable then the expression in the limit isn't even well-defined.

Comment: In highschool, so don't know what reimann Integral means , but if there is no counterexample at  highschool level, then it will probably not be asked . Thank you so much for your time and effort :)

Comment: Is there any good undergrad level book where I can read about all this ??

Comment: But...if you have worked a little (at least) with Riemann Integrals (=definite integrals, for our purposes), limits and differentials...haven't you seen a little *at least* about continuity? That's weird... You can take a peek at this: Theorem $1.50$ in page $30$ of https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf

Comment: The point where you wrote Reimann and Seeing your reputation, I just simply.... Stopped, ..... Okay , now it makes sense that if Reimann integrals are just .. Integrals